# how to make a update page with hasMany relatioins in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a form to update a model which has one to many relations. The structure is like

```
item => {[arg1, arg2], [arg1, arg2], [arg1, arg2]}
```

Each related model has two fields to be updated. I used the code below but I don't know how to code the controller side.

```
    @extends('app')

    @section('content')
        {!! Form::open(array('route' => array('Topic.update', $topic->id), 'method' => 'PATCH')) !!}
        {!! Form::label('title', 'Title') !!}
        {!! Form::text('title', $topic->title, array('maxlength' => 250)) !!}
        @foreach($topic->pairs as $key=>$value)
            <div>
                {!! Form::label('title', 'Pair ' . $key . ': ') !!}
                {!! Form::text('a' + $key, $value->arg1) !!}
                {!! Form::text('b' + $key, $value->arg2) !!}
            </div>
        @endforeach
        {!! Form::submit() !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    @endsection
```

When I dd($response->all()), it shows below:

```
array:9 [▼
  "_method" => "PATCH"
  "_token" => "dInpiSa6O2KIMftFnICQtVM873nUF2Zp2HlzeN4S"
  "title" => "Actors and Movies"
  0 => "Rain Man"
  1 => "Rush Hour"
  2 => "Edward Scissorhands"
  3 => "Titanic"
  4 => "The Devil Wears Prada"
  5 => "Fast & Furious"
]
```

The related items are not pairs but only arg1. So how should I code hasMany model? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` sign in PHP is not used for concatenation of strings. It is math operator. To concatenate strings you should use dot (`.`).

So change your code like this:

```
Form::text('a' . $key, $value->arg1)
Form::text('b' . $key, $value->arg2)
```

Because previously you were calculating the sum of `a` and `$key`, thats why you get numerical keys in the request.

If you wish to access your pairs in array, from the form request you can change the inputs to be arrays, like this:

```
Form::text('items[' . $key . '][arg1]', $value->arg1)
Form::text('items[' . $key . '][arg2]', $value->arg2)
```

With last example the request will look like this:

```
items => [
    [ arg1, arg2 ],
    [ arg1, arg2 ],
    ....
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used your method and the response data became this:  "arg1" => array:6 [▼
    0 => "Dustin Hoffman"
    1 => "Jackie Chan"
    2 => "Johnny Depp"
    3 => "Leonardo DiCaprio"
    4 => "Meryl Streep"
    5 => "Vin Diesel"
  ]
  "arg2" => array:6 [▼
    0 => "Rain Man"
    1 => "Rush Hour"
    2 => "Edward Scissorhands"
    3 => "Titanic"
    4 => "The Devil Wears Prada"
    5 => "Fast & Furious"
  ] Now I got two arrays for the two args which belong to the same model. Could I make it like this: "pairs" => array:6[ array:2[arg0 => "Dustin Hoffman", arg1 => "Rain Man"],... ]

Comment: @Yangrui Yes. Is this what you want? If no please explain what you expect the response to be.

Comment: just finished editing my last comment sorry I pressed the enter key and it submitted the form instead of breaking the line

Comment: @Yangrui I edited my comment see again last example and let me know if it works for you